# Organigram/Org chart in SharePoint online? any good free app or manual way to build it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, organization-chart

Anyone attempted to create a simple page with a manually built organigram or organization chart?

I am not talking about placing a PowerPoint page with smart art.

Any valuable free app from the store that can achieve that?

I need to have it on the page and not go to the delve profile of the person to see the org chart there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using SharePoint Online, I will suggest you to use [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) organisation chart web parts.

Below are some free samples on Git-Hub:

1. [React Tree Organization Web Part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-tree-orgchart).
2. [vue-js-org-chart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/vue-js-org-chart).
3. [Organisation Chart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-organisationchart).